# Hiding "Back" button in UITabViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, mobile, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

My storyboard sequence is as follows:

- UINavigationController
- LaunchScreenVC
- LoginVC or SignUPVC
- UITabBarController
- Tab1VC
- Tab2VC

I would like the back button to appear in LaunchScreenVC and LoginVC/SignUpVC but not Tab1VC and Tab2VC.

I placed `[self.tabBarController.navigationItem setHidesBackButton:YES animated:YES];` inside `viewWillAppear` of Tab1VC and TabVC2 but it had no effect. I read that this code should be called prior to instantiation of the VC but how am I able to do this since I am using storyboards?

Answer (score 4):

If you only want to hide the back button, you can do the following, add it to the tabBarController's viewDidLoad method.

```
self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = YES;
```

Comment: This code disables the back button but still leaves the word "back". Any suggestion to what I may be doing wrong? I subclassed UITabBarController and added this to viewDidLoad. @gabbler

Comment: So the "back" title is there but the button is not clickable? Maybe you can share more code.

Comment: That is correct. The back button becomes unresponsive and the "<" on the left of "back" is removed but the word "back" still remains. It shows up on both tabs, despite the fact that there is a leftBarButtonItem on the second tab (back shows underneath my image for leftBarButtonItem). I'd be happy to share some more code. What else would you like to see? @gabbler

Comment: I made a project with the same structure as yours,which worked fine for me,could you share a dummy project, leaving out important information, It is hard for me to pinpoint the problem.

Comment: I just stripped out the "guts" of my app (server implementation, etc) to upload a dummy project for you. When testing the stripped version of the app the back button does not appear. I'm not sure why my functional code would cause an issue with the back button not fully disappearing. @gabbler

Comment: After doing some more testing I've noticed that I do not have the issue when the user logs in or signs up and then is segued to the TabBarController. It is only when the app launches and immediately segues to the TabBarController. This happens when the app senses the user has previously logged in to prevent the user from having to manually log in on each application launch.